# Common Oauth with ADAL Login experience from Web and Windows Client App

Tags: c#, html, oauth, powerbi, adal

I am working on a product that can be accessed either as a `Windows Application(Desktop Client)` or through `HTML5 (Web Client)`. I am trying to `integrate Power BI reports` into my product. To access Power BI APIs that are needed to integrate Power BI reports, I created a Client ID using https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-a-client-app/

Now I created a class to access Power BI APIs using the Client ID and generate an access token using the below line:

```
token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, ClientID, new Uri(redirectUri),PromptBehavior.RefreshSession).AccessToken;
```

where

```
resourceUri = Uri to PowerBI APIs

redirectUri = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common (Multi-Tenant)
```

When on Desktop client, AcquireToken() method runs fine and gives me a Pop-up to enter AD Login credentials. But this method will fail when executed from HTML5 client and throws exception

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
```

I read in some blog that the Login window that Pops up for Oauth authentication is browser based. If so, why it fails to pop up when called from HTML5 client?

Is it possible to get similar pop up kind of `Login window using ADAL & Oauth for HTML5 client` as well.

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the popup you see on the desktop is a full fledged window form - which clearly cannot be opened from the code-behind of a website running on the server side.
You need to register two different clientIDs, one for the native client (desktop) as you already did, and one for the confidential client (website). That done, you need to drive an OpenId COnenct sign in +access token acquisition or you need to drive an oauth2 authorization request - all form server side code and using the browser surface as the mechanism to interact with the user. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/ for an example, just change the custom API with your Power BI one.
HTH

Comment: Thanks Vittorio on your prompt response.

Comment: So, this means we cannot have a single sign on experience for Public and Confidential clients?

Comment: Native apps represent their session via refresh tokens, web apps represent their sessions via cookies. Sharing the same clientID would not make it any easier to translate between session representations.